# Не подгружаются даннные из mysql в условии с get запросом

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, get, apache2

Есть php код, подключающийся к БД и записывающий определенные значения в переменные:

```
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'qwerty123', 'mecom');
if ($connect == false) { exit(); }
mysqli_query($connect, "SET NAMES utf8");

$categories = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `categories`");
$category_this = $_GET['category'];
$category = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE `path` = '$category_this'"));

$products = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `category_id` = '$category[id]'");
if (isset($_GET['product'])) {
    $product_this = $_GET['product'];
    $product = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `path` = '$product_this'"));
    $product_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `info` WHERE `product_id` = '$product[id]'"));

    $title = $product['name'];
} else if (isset($_GET['category'])) {
    $title = $category['name'];
} else {
    $title = 'Produkty';
}
```

Далее идет код, который определенным образом это все выводит в зависимости от get запроса:

```
    if (isset($_GET['category'])) {
        while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($products)) {
            echo 
'<li class="">
    <div class="product-item">
        <a href="?category=' . $category_this . '&product=' . $res['path'] . '"><img src="/Hungary/Mecom/assets/img/main/' . $res['img'] . '" alt="' . $res['name'] . '"></a>
        <h3>
            <a href="?category=' . $category_this . '&product=' . $res['path'] . '">' . $res['name'] . '</a>
        </h3>
    </div>
</li>';
        }
    } else
        while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($categories)) {
            echo 
'<li class="">
    <div class="category-item">
        <a href="?category=' . $res['path'] . '"><img src="/Hungary/Mecom/assets/img/main/' . $res['img'] . '" alt="' . $res['name'] . '"></a>
        <h3>
            <a href="?category=' . $res['path'] . '">' . $res['name'] . '</a>
        </h3>
    </div>
</li>';
        }
    }
```

Проблема заключается в том, что данные из "$categories" просто не загружаются при выполнении соответствующего условия. А условие "if (isset..." вполне работает. Я проверял все данные отдельно, и они нормально выводились. Но внутри этого условия почему-то ничего не работает.

Весь этот код находился в файле, где помимо него еще много html и php кода. Я поместил его в пустой файл и... Все работает! Но в основном файле я не обнаружил чего-либо, что могло бы препятствовать выполнению этого кода.

Вот содержимое файла:

```
<?php
    $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'qwerty123', 'mecom');
    if ($connect == false) { exit(); }
    mysqli_query($connect, "SET NAMES utf8");

    $categories = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `categories`");
    if (isset($_GET['category'])) {
        $category_this = $_GET['category'];
        $category = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE `path` = '$category_this'"));
        $category_title = $category['name'];
    } else {
        $category_title = 'PRODUKTY';
    }

    $products = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `category_id` = '$category[id]'");
    if (isset($_GET['product'])) {
        $product_this = $_GET['product'];
        $product = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `path` = '$product_this'"));
        $product_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `info` WHERE `product_id` = '$product[id]'"));

        $title = $product['name'];
    } else if (isset($_GET['category'])) {
        $title = $category['name'];
    } else {
        $title = 'Produkty';
    }
?>

<html>
<?php
    $descriiption = 'Mecom je výrobca kvalitných slovenských udenín. Pripravuje chutné a nevšedné kombinácie a recepty. S jeho pomocou sa bežný deň i slávnostná príležitosť premení na nezabudnuteľný zážitok plný chuti.';
    $keywords = 'mecom sk,Produkty,Súťaže,mecom klobasy,sutaz,slovenský mäsokombinát,mecom klobásy,velka sanca vyhrat,masokombinat,mecom natur parky,vyhrali,masokombinat hradok,mecom natur párky,online sutaz,masospracujuci,mecom parky,masovy priemysel,mecom párky,mäsokombinát,aspik,mäsokombinát hrádok,aspikovy vyrobok,mäsospracujúci,aspikový výrobok,mäsový priemysel,bratislavske parky,mecom,bratislavské párky,mecom gril,gril klobásky,mecom gril party,gril klobasky,mecom gril párty,jaternica,mecom group,jaternice,mecom group s&nbsp;r o,klobasa,mecom group sro,klobása,mecom premium quality,klobaska,mecom sk,klobáska,mecom sr,klobasky,pm zbrojniky,klobásky,pm zbrojníky,klobasy,potravinarsky priemysel,klobásy,potravinársky priemysel,krvavnicka,potravinarstvo,krvavnicky,potravinárstvo,krvavnička,skupina mecom,krvavničky,vyrobne zavody,viedenske,výrobné závody,kvalitne masove vyrobky,vyrobny zavod,kvalitné mäso,výrobný závod,kvalitné mäso výrobky,zbrojniky,lahodkova sunka,zbrojníky,lahodky,schneider,lahôdková šunka,kaiser,lahôdky,csabahus,maso,certifikát kvality,maso najvyssej kvality,certifikat kvality,masova,certifikát IFS,masova pena,certifikaty IFS,masove,dlhoročná tradícia,masove peny,dlhorocna tradicia,masove produkty,zážitok plný chuti,masove vyrobky,zazitok plny chuti,masovy,recepty,masovy produkt,oslava,masovy vyrobok,pohostenie,mäso,chlebíčky,mäsová,chlebicky,mäsová pena,celiakia,mäsové,vhodné pre celiatikov,mäsové peny,bezlepkové,mäsové produkty,bezlepková,mäsové výrobky,bezlepkova,mäsový,bezlepkove,mäsový produkt,kontrola kvality,mäsový výrobok,preprava a skladovanie mäsových výrobkov,narez,ako variť párky,nárez,ako spravne varit parky,narezy,vyrobené na slovensku,nárezy,vyrobene na slovensku,natur parky,oblozeno chlebicky,natur párky,co davate na chlebicky,gril horčicové,ako robit chlebicky,gril horcicove,obložené chlebíčky,parky,čo dávate na chlebíčky,párky,ako robiť chlebíčky,parok,párok,pasteta,pastety,paštéta,paštéty,polosucha salama,polosuchá saláma,safaladky,safaládky,salama,saláma,salamy,salámy,slanina,slaniny,snack,spekacky,spracovanie masa,spracovanie mäsa,sucha salama,suchá saláma,sunka,sunky,špekačky,šunka,šunky,tlacenka,tlacenky,tlačenka,tlačenky,udena slanina,udená slanina,gril bavorské,gril bavorske,gril syrové,gril syrove,gril mix,gril paprikove,gril cesnakove,gril zaudene,viedenské párky,spišské párky,spisske parky,kvalitne parky,kriváň,krivan,hydinove parky,pastierske parky,desiatove parky,kaiser parky,levocske parky,ludove parky,morcacie parky,morcacie parky so syrom,frankfurtske parky,obycajne parky,pikantne parky,ipelska klobasa,gazdovska,rusnacka klobasa,sedliacka,pikant spirala,labuznicka,bacon,oravska,';
    include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Hungary/Mecom/sk/parts/head.php';
?>
<body>
    <div id="bodyCont" class="nofixed">
        <?php include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Hungary/Mecom/sk/parts/header.php' ?>
        <div id="pageCont">
            <div id="pageContIn">


    <section>
        <div class="section section-product-list">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="container-in">
                    <h2><?=$category_title?></h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <?php
        if (isset($_GET['product'])) {
            echo 
            '<div class="section section-product-detail">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="container-in">
                        <div class="product-detail">
                            <h2>' . $product['name'] . '</h2>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <img src="' . $product['img'] . '" alt="' . $product['name'] . '" style="height:440.896px">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6 hidden-xs">
                                    <div class="product-detail-info product-detail-info-1" data-shape="prkenko" style="height: 440.896px;">
                                        <div class="product-detail-info-content">
                                            <p>
                                                <span class="product-detail-info-label product-detail-info-new">
                                                </span>
                                                        <span></span>
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                <span class="product-detail-info-label">EKP</span>
                                                    <span>' . $product_info['number'] . '</span>
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                <span class="product-detail-info-label">Skladovacia teplota</span>
                                                    <span>' . $product_info['temperature'] . '</span>
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                <span class="product-detail-info-label">Hmotnosť </span>
                                                    <span>' . $product_info['mass'] . '</span>
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                <span class="product-detail-info-label">Trvanlivosť </span>
                                                    <span>' . $product_info['durability'] . '</span>
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                <span class="product-detail-info-label">Produktove balenie</span>
                                                    <span>' . $product_info['packaging'] . '</span>
                                            </p>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">
                                            <div class="row pictograms">
                                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                        <img src="/Hungary/Mecom/assets/img/main/pictogram-lepek.png" alt="Bez gluténový" title="Bez gluténový" class="img-responsive">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-3">

                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                                        <img src="/Hungary/Mecom/assets/img/main/pictogram-sk.png" alt="Vyrobeno na Slovensku" title="Vyrobeno na Slovensku" class="img-responsive">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <h3>Zloženie:</h3>
                                    <p>' . $product['composition'] . '</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <h3>Výživové údaje na 100 g výrobku:</h3>
                                    <div>' . $product['fooddata'] . '</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>';
        }
    ?>

    <section>
        <div class="section section-product-list">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="container-in">
                    <ul class="product-list">
                        <?php
                            if (isset($_GET['category'])) {
                                while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($products)) {
                                    echo 
                                    '<li class="">
                                        <div class="product-item">
                                            <a href="?category=' . $category_this . '&product=' . $res['path'] . '"><img src="/Hungary/Mecom/assets/img/main/' . $res['img'] . '" alt="' . $res['name'] . '"></a>
                                            <h3>
                                                <a href="?category=' . $category_this . '&product=' . $res['path'] . '">' . $res['name'] . '</a>
                                            </h3>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>';
                                }
                            } else {
                                while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($categories)) {
                                    echo
                                    '<li class="">
                                        <div class="category-item">
                                            <a href="?category=' . $res['path'] . '"><img src="/Hungary/Mecom/assets/img/main/' . $res['img'] . '" alt="' . $res['name'] . '"></a>
                                            <h3>
                                                <a href="?category=' . $res['path'] . '">' . $res['name'] . '</a>
                                            </h3>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>';
                                }
                            }
                        ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>


            </div>

        </div>
        <?php include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Hungary/Mecom/sk/parts/footer.php' ?>

        </div>
                <div id="cookie" class="cookie-cont">
                    <div>
                        <p>
                            <span><a href="https://www.google.com/intl/sk/policies/technologies/cookies/" target="_blank">Tieto webové stránky používajú cookies. Ak budete pokračovať bez zmien, s použitím cookies súhlasíte.</a></span>
                            <a class="btn cookie-bt" href="/cookie-ok/">Rozumiem</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <script>
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        var ci = Cookies.get("cookie-info");
                        if (ci != undefined) {
                            $('.cookie-cont').hide();
                        }
                        $('.cookie-bt').click(function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            Cookies.set("cookie-info", "mecom");
                            $('.cookie-cont').hide();
                            return false;
                        });
                    });
                    </script>
                </div>
    </div>

    <div id="topBtCont" class="nofixed">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="#" class="topBt"></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
            i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
                (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
            }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
            m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
        })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

        ga('create', 'UA-43498603-1', 'mecom.sk');
        ga('send', 'pageview');

    </script>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Все решил сам. Оказалось, что дело в подключаемом файле "header.php". Там также использовался цикл while с переменной categories. Из-за обработки обеих переменных с помощью mysqli_fetch_assoc вызов этой команды в следующем цикле возвращал null.